# Pass the user id to an http parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters

Good morning, I have a login that returns me the UserID from the server, I store it in an instance of Shared Preferences, and I want to use it as a parameter so that in the main screen, it shows five recent records, also brought from the database.

I attach the code of the login, I emphasize that I was trying to pass some arguments by means of the routes, which are the UserID and the Role of the user, to show him a screen in special.

```
Future<void> login(email, password) async{
    try{
      var url = 'serverurl';
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), 
      body:
        {
          'Email' : email,
          'Password' : password
        }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));

        var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(datos);
        if(response.body != '0'){
          guardarDatos(datos['UserID'], datos['Role']);
          if('Role' == 'admin'){
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/AdminPage', arguments: {'UserID':UserId, 'Role': Role});

           } else {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserPage', arguments: {'UserID': UserId, 'Role': Role});

          }
        } else{
          //Cuadro de diálogo que indica que los datos son incorrectos.
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return const AlertLogin();
              });
          print('Usuario Incorrecto');
        }
    } on TimeoutException catch(e){
      print('Tiempo de proceso excedido.');
    } on Error {
      print('http error.');
    }
  }
```

The following, is the code for the main screen, where I plan to pass the user id as a parameter in the URL of the http.get, to get the user records, for example number 1.

```
//HTTP Request
Future<List<Record>> fetchRecord() async {
  //final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-15257.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/1')); Este es estático.

  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();

    return parsed.map<Record>((json) => Record.fromMap(json)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load records.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your code for main screen, I am assuming you are asking how to retrieve your arguments passed through named routes. Here's what you need to do:

Define a variable:

```
final user = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

You can use this user variable to access the UserID and Email just like this:

```
print('User Email: ${user.UserID}');
print('User Email: ${user.Role}');
```

Its like calling a map's value using its key.

So this is how your final code might look like:

```
Future<List<Record>> fetchRecord() async {
  final user = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments; // You can use this variable directly in your links

  //final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-15257.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/1')); Este es estático.

  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();

    return parsed.map<Record>((json) => Record.fromMap(json)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load records.');
  }
}
```

Hope that solves your problem. Feel free to clear up any confusions.

Comment: Thanks, in a few more moments I will try it, just one more question, the correct way to insert it in the URL would be
```final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://e5ac-45-65-152-57.ngrok.io/get/fiverecords/$user'));``` ?

Comment: Instead of just $user use ${user.UserID} if you want to pass the user ID in the URL. 'user' is just a map of keys and values that you passed in your arguments from the previous screen's Navigator call. You can try printing the variables inserted into the url to make sure how it looks :)